# Filtering on CASE Statement on WHERE clause including variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I would like to filter out 'TR' records for when @BU = 'ES'. This works perfectly fine for 'ES' but when I run this query for another country, i.e. 'SE' it does not return the row count I expect. 
expected row count: 28941
row count returned: 28916

I know this is to do with the filer of 'TR'. How do I get this to work as it is for Spain and also when I run it for other BUs.

'TR' only needs to be filtered out for 'ES' only.

```
declare @BU varchar(2);
set @BU = 'SE';

select case
           when @BU = 'ES' then
               p.PanelClass
           else
               'b'
       end as L1
from Panels                  p
    left outer join Slots    sl
        on sl.ID = p.ID
    left outer join Packages pa
        on pa.ID = p.ID
where p.Status = 1
      and case
              when @BU = 'ES' then
                  p.PanelClass
              else
                  'b'
          end <> 'TR';
```

Comment: Forgot to mention. Status has to be filtered to 1 in all cases.

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR constructions in the WHERE clause, instead of case expressions.

Comment: @jarlh I was using AND/OR when the field L1 was a field directly from panels. However, since it is different between ES and other BUs. This was changed to a case statement.

Comment: @jarlh I was using this before....where p.Status = '1'
      and
      (
          (
              convert(varchar(2), '${BusinessUnit}') = 'ES'
              and left(ltrim(p.PanelClass), 2) <> 'TR'
          )
          or (convert(varchar(2), '${BusinessUnit}') <> 'ES')
      );

Comment: Using a `CASE` will cause the query to be non-SARGable. So too, however, will be things like `left(ltrim(p.PanelClass), 2)` Why not use a `LIKE`?

Comment: Why tag 3 different versions of SQL Server here too, 2 of qhich are completely unsupported?

Comment: @Larnu  Apologies about the tags.I have removed them now.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
declare @BU varchar(2);
set @BU = 'SE';

select case
           when @BU = 'ES' then
               p.PanelClass
           else
               'b'
       end as L1
from Panels                  p
    left outer join Slots    sl
        on sl.ID = p.ID
    left outer join Packages pa
        on pa.ID = p.ID
where p.Status = 1
      and 'TR' <> case when @BU = 'ES' then p.PanelClass else 'b' end;
```